# Which is correct? "...watch her is talking...", "...watch her was talking...", or "...watched her was talking..."?

Tags: sentence-construction, modal-verbs, sentence-structure, clauses

I have three sentences. Is there anybody who can tell me which would be correct?

a) How could he **watch** his girlfriend **is talking** with him (another guy)?

b) How could he **watch** that his girlfriend **was talking** with him (another guy)?

c) How could he **watched**  his girlfriend **was talking** with him (another guy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either say

> watch his girlfriend talking to another guy.

or use the word **while**

> watch while his girlfriend is talking

For clarity, you should not use **he** and **him** to refer to different people in the same sentence. The fact that you needed to clarify **another guy** shows the problem. Although we might be able to infer the meaning we can't be sure which he/him is which person. Going a step further we also have **his** in the sentence, and we need to make sure there is no ambiguity about which person's girfriend this is.

So we say

> How could Bill watch his girlfriend talking to another guy?

or, if we've very recently had other references to Bill, so it's very clear who **he** is,

> I've never understood Bill.
>
> How could he watch his girlfriend talking to another guy like that?

Now in speech we could use our vocal inflections to indicate that **he** and **him** are different people.

> How could he just watch his girfriend talking to *(rising inflection, emphasis)* **him**.

But when writing, or speaking in a more formal context, take special care to ensure that it is clear which **he** or **him** you mean.

Comment: How could he watch that his girlfriend was talking with Andy? is it correct in sense of tense?

Comment: @Omar - remove the “that” and “was": _How could he watch his girlfriend talking with Andy?_ Or, include the word “while”: _How could he watch **while** his girlfriend **was** talking with Andy?_

Comment: @J.R. Thank you so much. So the correct form is, "How could he watch while his girlfriend was talking with Andy?"  and "was" used instead of "is" because of subordinate clause from past. Am I right ?

Comment: @Omar - It’s: “How **could** he watch while his girlfriend **was** talking?” Or: “How **can** he watch while his girlfriend **is** talking?"

Comment: @J.R. Now my confusion has gone. Thank you so much.